# What is the use of API login id in authorize payment gateway

Tags: android, payment-gateway, authorize.net

I'm getting the same repeated answer from every source.

> The API Login ID is a complex value that identifies your account to
>   the payment gateway when submitting transaction requests from your
>   website. **While not valid for logging into the Merchant Interface, its
>   purpose is similar to a login ID**—it's like your website logging onto
>   the payment gateway. The API Login ID is at least eight characters in
>   length, includes uppercase and lowercase letters, numbers, and/or
>   symbols.

But I am not getting the role of API login id. Where/When should I used it?

One more problem: Is their need to perform password based authentication for merchant even if I am not creating a POS.

Why do I need to store password in application?

Comment: -1 for what. It will be very helful if you post a comment with -1 so that i can know i have done this particular thing wrong. Thanks

Comment: Here is your answer from Authorize.net : http://developer.authorize.net/hello_world/common_setup_questions/#API_login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API Login and Transaction Key are used for a server-based application to authenticate to the gateway.  However it should not be used on a mobile device.

The Android SDK allows you to accept payments using a mobile device in a mobile point of sale configuration where the merchant holds the device.  It cannot be used to accept payments on a customer's mobile device.

Comment: " It cannot be used to accept payments on a customer's mobile device." Why?. How to integrate my application with authorize payment gateway so that customer can pay to merchant whenever they want

Comment: currently i am saving merchantId and password in my application. and from sandbox account it is paying to a particular merchant whose id is saved in the application

Comment: please communicate with me ! i am trying to communicate with tech guys fot support. It will be very full if we can chat for a minute @rhldr